# How to take corresponding entry from second table and update in first table - Mysql

Tags: mysql

Old

```
table_products - pid, pname;
table_categories - cid, cname
table_product_category - pid, cid
```

New

```
table_products - id, name, category_id;
table_categories - cid, cname
```

As a product can belongs to only one category, it is decided that merge table_products and table_product_category table in one table. For that a new column has been added in table_products.

Now what is the best way to add corresponding category_id in table_products from table_product_category table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the column using `alter table` and then update the value:

```
alter table table_products add category_id int;

update table_products p join
       table_product_category pc
       on pc.pid = p.id
    set p.category_id = pc.cid;
```

You should probably also add a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table table_products
    add constraint fk_product_categoryid
        foreign key (category_id) references table_category(id);
```